# After upgrade kali linux some fonts have been missed

Tags: linux, kali-linux, upgrade, fontconfig

I upgraded kali linux 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 into 4.5.0-kali1-amd64 . After that some fonts has been missed.i tried to fix it.but i couldn't. This is an example error of that.. in login screen also the save problem has been occured.

[image: a notification error example]

Note: i upgraded kali using settings -> details -> check for update

After that i tried using apt-get upgrade and apt-get dist-upgrade.but yet the problem has not solved!

Hell me to fix this.

Thank You,
Chathula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it...

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstal fonts-cantarell
```